# Output redirect for python

Tags: python, linux, output

I have python code that looks like this:

```
cmd = './job1'
print(cmd)
os.system(cmd)
```

If I run this, the output looks like:

```
./job1
done.
```

But if I run it with output re-direct, say:

python mycode.py > out1.log

then 'out1.log' looks like this:

```
done.
./job1
```

basically, if I run the python code using output redirect, all the os.system(cmd) output goes first to the output file, the output from python goes at the very end.
Is there a way to make the output redirected to a file the same as screen output?

Comment: Perhaps flush stdout before running `os.system`?

Comment: `print` function has an optional `flush` argument that defaults to `False`, just do `print(cmd, flush=True)`

Comment: print(cmd, flush=True) doesn't seem to work with 2.7.9 version I am using

Comment: oh, sorry having brackets around `print`, I assumed you were in python 3, no you will need to do `sys.stdout.flush()` manually